# AngularJS controller, template and routing issue

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I am having a few issues getting my head around why this is not working:

template

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in get">
            {{ x.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

controller

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('SubstancesCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.get = [{name: "LOL"}];
    });
```

routes

```
angular.module('app')
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/',           { controller: 'PostsCtrl',      templateUrl:     '/templates/posts.html' })
  .when('/register',   { controller: 'RegisterCtrl',   templateUrl:     '/templates/register.html' })
  .when('/login',      { controller: 'LoginCtrl',      templateUrl: '/templates/login.html' })
  .when('/substances', { controller: 'SubstancesCtrl', templateUrl: '/templates/substances.html'})
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='app'>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/app.css'>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller='ApplicationCtrl'>
    <nav class='navbar navbar-default'>
      <div class='container'>
        <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
          <li><a href='/#/'>Posts</a></li>
          <li><a href='/#/register'>Register</a></li>
          <li><a href='/#/login'>Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="/#/substances">Substances</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p ng-if='currentUser' class='navbar-text navbar-right'>
          Signed in as {{currentUser.username}}
        </p>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class='container' ng-view></div>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.4/angular.js'></script>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.4/angular-route.js'></script>
    <script src='/app.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can see that the template is being replaced by the ng-view directive however the get variable is not being treated in the manner i thought it would: i thought i would get one list item node with the value of LOL

Comment: Um... what? You assigned the string to the `lol` property, but in your template you never use it. In your template you try to call a function called `get`, which isn't defined anywhere. Why do you expect that to work?

Comment: I corrected that typo; i was playing about, please assume the lol property is called get.

Comment: Well, now you have three problems. First of all, you're calling `get()` like it's a function, but in your controller you've defined it as a simple value, a string. Second of all, `ngRepeat` expects an array, not a plain value. Third, you're accessing the `name` property of each element, so even if you *did* wrap the value in an array, it still wouldn't work because you'd need to wrap the value in an object. I get the feeling you need to do some more reading to figure out how Angular (or maybe programming in general) works.

Comment: I appreciate your help in highlighting the issues there, i have made the adjustments in the code needed to resolve the 3 issues you have highlighted, it still does not resolve the issue. Your right, i have only just started with angular and maybe I need to take a break from it as this has made it apparent i have made some laughable mistakes; i was just hoping to get the issues resolved prior to calling it a night.

Comment: it's ok, thanks for the help, I have identified the last issue; it seems nodemon config was neglecting to deploy the changes on account I forgot to add the additional files to be checked for differences. Meaning the files being served were not the updated versions

Answer (score 0):

You angular module has not been created, You should declare your module in `app.js`. As you are using angular routing you need to include its module in your `app` module.

```
angular.module('app',['ngRoute'])
```

Also you need to update your Angular to stable versions `1.4.4` is stable one, because you are using `1.3.0-rc.4` in which `rc` stands for `release candidate` which is pre-release version, which may have bug in most of the cases. Thats why I told you to go for stable version of AngularJS. You could also use close stable version which is `1.3.14`

Additionally your template has `<li ng-repeat="x in get()">` but `get` function is not defined in the scope, resultant would be nothing would be render on the UI.

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('SubstancesCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.lol = "LOL";
    $scope.get = function(){
       //write a code here which will return list
       //so that ng-repeat will loop through the list
       //& will show that data on HTML
       //something like below
       return {"name": "LOL"}; //in real case there must be something different object to return.
    }
});
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by this, all my other controllers are made in the same way and they seem to be working fine, i am also curious how you know i am not using angular 1.4.4

Comment: thanks I see what you mean now, I broke that out into a module.js file which contains all the additional dependencies that I need to include, i should have remembered that.

Comment: great..Glad to hear that my answer helped you..Thanks :)

Comment: It was my fault for spending far too long on getting the websocket implementation working and then moving on to this when i am dog tired, cheers for the patience

Answer (score 0):

Alexis King was quite correct in that there were 3 very embarrassing issues with the code, it should have looked like this ( -_- )

template

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in get">
            {{ x.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

controller

```
angular.module('app')
     .controller('SubstancesCtrl', function ($scope) {
         $scope.get = [{name: "LOL"}];
    });
```

routes were exactly the same.

The biggest issue however was in my gulp script which failed to pick up changes in these new files, I have rewrote the build script to ensure all files from the directories containing these files now are watched and all changes are reflected in the browser.

My excuse: need more coffee.